# How do I remove 'git' from the start of my Git aliases?

Tags: git

How do I set up an alias for Git where I do not have to type in git?

So for example I have an alias of 'add' and it performs git add -A

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Many thanks.

Comment: create aliases in the shell

Comment: Do you have any help on how to do this? This is on Windows I should add.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has alias too:

```
doskey add=git add -A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your shell directly.

Assuming you use bash, do this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ga="git add -A"
```

Then, just open another shell (or run `source ~/.bashrc`), and type `ga`